# Can not access any host from shell while they are accessible from Firefox/Chrome

Tags: networking, proxy

OS is under a proxy. I use cntlm. Company adds a root certificate to all certificates. I have a problem accessing any host from shell. For example:

```
svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin/trunk spamassassin
```

returns

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin/trunk': could not connect to server (http://svn.apache.org)
```

`ping` command behaves the same:

```
ping svn.apache.org
PING svn.geo.apache.org (160.45.251.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

is stuck forever.

Is there something I have missed in configuration?

=============

UPDATE

I have finally fixed the problem with remote port forwarding from a windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you configured SVN to use the proxy?

```
/home/you/.subversion/servers
```

and put

```
http-proxy-host = proxy.mydomain
http-proxy-port = 3128
http-proxy-username = user
http-proxy-password = pass
```

For your console, export the environement variable:

```
export http_proxy=http://DOMAIN\USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT/
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Yes I have configured SVN servers to use http-proxy, since the proxy is cntlm it looks like: 
    http-proxy-host = localhost
    http-proxy-port = 3128

Environment variables are configured to point to the same host and port:

    http_proxy=http://localhost:3128/